# Storing Individual Values From List Box As Variables

Tags: c#, listbox, sqlconnection

I have a listbox which is currently reading fields from my database. I would like to be able to store each individual values that I am reading in as strings and ints. There will four field types, these are Surname, Forename, EmployeeID, PaymentDate. How do I split and store the selected item of combined fields as separate variables.

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dsEmployeePayment.Tables["EmployeePayment"].Rows)  
 {
    lstPaymentID_Edit.Items.Add(
    dr["Surname"].ToString() + ", " 
    + dr["Forename"] + ", " 
    + dr["EmployeeID"].ToString() + ", " 
    + dr["PaymentDate"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating an object for the items you are adding to the `ListBox`.

```
public class Employee 
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", Surname, Forename, EmployeeID, PaymentDate);
    }
 }
```

Your class will contain all the fields in the correct types. The `ListBox` will call `ToString` on your item, and display it in the same fashion as you do now.

The `DataRow` processing would happen like this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsEmployeePayment.Tables["EmployeePayment"].Rows)  
{
   lstPaymentID_Edit.Items.Add(
      new Employee {
         Surname =  (string)dr["Surname"],
         Forename = (string)dr["Forename"],
         EmployeeID = (int)dr["EmployeeID"],
         PaymentDate = (DateTime)dr["PaymentDate"]
      }
   );
}
```

The real magic happens when you do something with the selected item:

```
Employee selectedEmployee = lstPaymentID_Edit.SelectedItem as Employee;
DateTime paymentDate = selectedEmployee.PaymentDate;
```